# Twitter Reverse Auth iPhone

Tags: api, twitter

Has anyone been able to successfully get a user's OAuth token using reverse auth? My app has reverse auth permissions but I'm having a hard time getting a valid authentication token. I am using OAuthconsumer and I'm a bit confused on how to modify the OAuth call for the additional x_auth_mode mode.

I keep getting

```
Failed to validate oauth signature and token
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you know the example code from Sean Cook (Developer at Twitter)?
https://github.com/seancook/TWiOS5ReverseAuthExample

His solution is working and is more detailed than the Twitter Documentation...
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth

Answer (score 0):

I found the seancook example convoluted to the extent that the process seems much more complicated than it actually is. Here is the simple essence of reverse auth:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [TDOAuth URLRequestForPath:@"/oauth/request_token" POSTParameters:@{@"x_auth_mode": @"reverse_auth"}  host:@"api.twitter.com" consumerKey:APIKey consumerSecret:APISecret accessToken:nil tokenSecret:nil];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    id oauth = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    SLRequest *reverseAuth = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"] parameters:@{
        @"x_reverse_auth_target": APIKey,
        @"x_reverse_auth_parameters": oauth
    }];
    reverseAuth.account = account;
    [reverseAuth performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        id creds = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id credsDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        for (__strong id pair in [creds componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"]) {
            pair = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            credsDict[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@", credsDict);
    }];
}];
```

My example uses [TDOAuth](https://github.com/tweetdeck/TDOAuth), but any OAuth library will do.